# helm install incubator/fluentd-cloudwatch fails with Error: failed to download

Tags: fluentd, kubernetes-helm

I tried to install the helm chart with:
`helm install incubator/fluentd-cloudwatch`

I get the error:
`Error: failed to download "incubator/fluentd-cloudwatch" (hint: running`helm repo update`may help)`

doing `helm repo update` didn't help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, helm does not include the incubator charts.

To add the incubator charts, run:

`$ helm repo add incubator http://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-charts-incubator`